# What is the probability of having 5 green and white capplets and all 5 of them have the same color in the same side?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of having 5 green and white caplets and all 5 of them have the same color on the same side?[Image to Ilustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq5Gl.jpg)

Comment: I assume that there is a machine that loads the packages like that all the time... so 100%.  If the caplets were randomly loaded then $\frac {1}{2^4}$

Comment: Can you please explain why it is 1/16? I first thought it was 1/32, since there are 5 caplets, but I wasn't sure, that's why I asked. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's $\frac{1}{16}$ is because you originally have $\frac{1}{2^5}=\frac{1}{32}$, but there are two cases: either the greens are on the left or the greens are on the left. Each has equal probability $\frac{1}{32}$, so the total probability is $\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{32}=\frac{1}{16}.$